# How to check file integrity of download if checksum value is not posted

Tags: windows-7, download, checksum, data-integrity

I plan to download a large amount of files from [this website](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/?).

There are no checksums posted on this website (that I know of). Is there a way I can generate a checksum from the file on the server (perhaps via some Command Line Interface) and then compare that to my downloaded file?

I'm using Windows 7 32-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, unless the server is yours and you have access to file system.
But simply try to find the same file from another source and compare 2 downloads. Uncle google will help on this.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Haha, I've been waiting for like a month for an answer. I was afraid that would be the case, but I appreciate the closure.